# What is the proper use of Keras TextVectorization function when vectorizing tweets?

Tags: python, keras, tfidfvectorizer

I am having some difficulty using [Keras' TextVectorization function](https://keras.io/api/layers/preprocessing_layers/core_preprocessing_layers/text_vectorization/).  I have gone through the documentation pages and have studied the code, but this does not seem to help when dealing with a dataset.

I am working on a dataset of tweets and have been able to successfully make predictions on a binary classification of tweets using [sklearn's TfidfVectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html).  The code that I have written using skearn is:

```py
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

vectorizer_tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english', max_df=0.5, min_df=0.01)

X_train = np.array(X_train).tolist()
X_train = list(map(''.join, X_train))

X_val = np.array(X_val).tolist()
X_val = list(map(''.join, X_val))

X_train_tfIdf = vectorizer_tfidf.fit_transform(X_train).toarray()
X_val_tfIdf = vectorizer_tfidf.transform(X_val).toarray()
print(vectorizer_tfidf.get_feature_names_out()[:5])
```

Would it be possible if someone can show me the correct way to accomplish this task in Keras?  I have studied sevaral websites and tutorials, and have not been able to come up with a suitable solution to this problem.

Comment: So, you have succesfully done the task in sklearn, but now want to do the same in Keras? Can you show what you've done using Keras and where you get stuck?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include any new information, code in comments is not very readable.

Comment: `import tensorflow as tf

# Create the layer.
vectorize_layer = tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization(
   output_mode='int',
   output_sequence_length=max_len)

vectorize_layer.adapt(X_train)
#vectorize_layer.adapt(X_val)

vocab = vectorize_layer.get_vocabulary()
print(len(vocab))

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.string))
model.add(vectorize_layer)

input_data = X_val
y_pred = model.predict(input_data)
print(y_pred.shape)`

Comment: What? Why not just [edit] the question?

Comment: I have found a tutorial on the keras documentation, which I think answers my question:- https://keras.io/examples/nlp/multi_label_classification/